# Question on integral computation

Tags: integration

I am trying to actually compute $\int \sqrt{\cosh{y}-\cos{x}}e^{inx} dx$ 
. Would someone please provide me a mathematical approach into solving $\int \sqrt{2-\cos{x}}e^{inx} dx$ and i shall figure out the rest.Please note that $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the imaginary part of $\int\sqrt{2-\cos x} e^{inx} dx$ you can use the trick of starting with the ansatz that the integral is the form 
$$
(k+\sqrt{2-\cos x} \left( \sum_{m=0}^n a_m \sin(mx) \right)
$$
fro any particular $n$; the general form for arbitrary $n$ is too difficult for me.

For the real part the same type of ansatz fails because the indefinitie integral involves elliptic functions.

I'm afraid the situation when you replace $2$ by $\cosh x$ is worse yet.